# What does error code 40162 means?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I saw this from our logs and I searched about this error in various search engines but I found nothing. Here it is:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 40162.
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

I think this happened executing a LINQ statement where we are retrieving items from the database based on the stack trace.

Comment: Hi jean27, could you specify the database you are using?

Comment: @Anthill We are using SQL Azure.

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: @AmiramKorach The exception I quoted above is the inner exception.  The outer exception is "An error occurred while executing the command definition."  Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what is the code that caused the exception? Can you reproduce it?

Comment: @AmiramKorach It includes several .Include statements, a .Where statement and an .OrderBy statement.  According to the stack trace, it occurred while the .OrderBy statement is executed.  This is the first time our program throwed this type of exception.  I just want to know what the error code means. Thanks.

Comment: I think the code means what it says

Comment: Is not there more inner exceptions there? Even if you quoted an inner exception it still can have another inner exception. This, and showing the query may help.

Comment: @Pawel There are no other inner exceptions that are listed on our logs.  And this happened while in production.  Thanks, anyway.